# Changing loss value and a frozen accuracy value in binary classification using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

Simple example task of binary classification. Features are 2D array with values in [-1,1]. (Dataset is from make_circles from sklearn.datasets)

My model :

````
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 
                                input_shape=(2,),
                                kernel_regularizer='l2'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 
                                kernel_regularizer='l2'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.softmax))

model.compile (optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop() , 
               loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()]) ```
````

The output is that loss in decreasing while binary accuracy is frozen at 0.5067 during all epochs.

```
Epoch 1/10
45/45 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.7802 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7563 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 2/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7605 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7486 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 3/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7487 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7425 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 4/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7396 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7368 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 5/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7320 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7306 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 6/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7254 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7269 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 7/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7203 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7211 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 8/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7157 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7158 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 9/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7118 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7116 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 10/10
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7082 - binary_accuracy: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.7099 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.4400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic error that most of us got while starting to learn Binary Classification. The reason your accuracy is **frozen** is that in the last layer there is only one unit. Since it's a binary classification task, there should of 2 units in the last layer. Your code will be like this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 
                                input_shape=(2,),
                                kernel_regularizer='l2'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 
                                kernel_regularizer='l2'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, 
                                activation= tf.keras.activations.softmax))

model.compile (optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop() , 
               loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
```

Now when you pass your input data from the model, As an output you will get an array(tensor) of length 2 like `[0.37, 0.63]`. If you take a closer look you will see both the entries of this array sum to `1.0` (0.37+0.63). It actually means your given input belongs to `class 1` with a probability of `0.63` and belong to `class 0` with a probability 0f `0.37`

Whereas In your case (with 1 unit in the final layer) it will only give results like `[0.78]` or `[0.21]` which doesn't make any sense regarding which class your input image is belonging to.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the softmax activation function with the sigmoid activation function for your last layer:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Softmax is used for [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification).

EDIT: Expectedly, a softmax activation on (batch_size, 1) dimensional data gives a tensor of only 1's:

```
tf.keras.activations.softmax(tf.constant([[-55.], [.1], [102.]))

>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
>> array([[1.],
>>        [1.],
>>        [1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

However, I'm not sure how your loss is decreasing steadily.